# Exporting/Importing Fields

Tags: field

Is there an easy way for Importing/Exporting Fields?

I'm just working on a selection of Global fields that I'd like to be able to add for each client site. These would be things like Contact Details, Social Links, etc.

**EDIT**: I created [FieldManager](https://github.com/engram-design/FieldManager) for this!

Comment: Would absolutely love to see this added as well. Seems like a very valuable feature to save us all a great deal of time.

Comment: As [Brad says](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/1665/45), its on their radar. Still, could be worthwhile to [submit it as a feature request](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests).

Comment: For now, using [ArtVandelay](https://github.com/xodigital/ArtVandelay) is a great option!

Answer (score 7):

I always write [migrations](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/migrations) to do this.

[Here's](https://gist.github.com/boboldehampsink/50961639ee909b4ae89c) and example for changing the label of a field.

You could, of course, do whatever you want - modify fieldlayouts, add/modify/remove fields, etc.

**UPDATE**

Nowadays I use the [Schematic Plugin](https://github.com/itmundi/schematic) to transfer all kinds of settings (fields, fieldlayouts, settings etc.) over different setups.

Comment: Do you have an option for Windows users? Schematic seems to only work on linux.

Comment: Not at the moment, no. But if you can create an issue for it we will have a look.

Comment: False alarm, sorry :) It worked.

Answer (score 6):

Check out https://github.com/engram-design/FieldManager

I was looking for a way to duplicate a matrix field to make another variant. This works perfectly for cloning fields and seems to have Export/Import options with a good UI for selecting which field you want to export.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, there isn't a native way to do this.

But it's been [discussed](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+SamHibberd/posts/1p8dHMfFA2G) many times before and it's still on our radar.

Comment: Hi Brad, any updates on this feature?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Is this still on the radar? is there an official request for this as I couldn't find one.... (I'm sure it  must be there!)

Comment: @BradBell I would appreciate an update on this topic!